# Herkunft von „Der Apfel fällt nicht weit vom Stamm“

Tags: etymology, proverb

In den Tiefen des Internet entdeckte ich eine vermeintliche Erklärung der Herkunft des Sprichwortes:

> Der Apfel fällt nicht weit vom Stamm.

Behauptet wird [hier](http://www.sprichwoerter.net/content/view/1467/1/), es handle sich um ein Ritual der alten Germanen. Diese Erklärung war irgendwie vollkommen anders, als das, was ich irgendwann mal dazu gehört hatte. Welchen Ursprung hat dieses Sprichwort (wirklich)?

Comment: Mir fällt gerade erst auf, dass die Überschrift eine Frage nach der Herkunft andeutet, während im Text nach der Bedeutung gefragt wird. - Ebenfalls für close gevoted. Imho muss diese Frage anschließend sogar gelöscht werden.

Comment: Hier mal der Link zur [Meta-Diskusison](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/403/1224)

Comment: Wie die Alten sungen, so zwitschern auch die Jungen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Zuerst die Bedeutung des Sprichworts ([laut Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Der_Apfel_f%C3%A4llt_nicht_weit_vom_Stamm)):

> [1a] deutet an, dass ein Kind Eigenschaften und Verhaltensweisen von den Eltern übernimmt.
>   [1b] im übertragenen Sinne; bildlich: abstammende Dinge, Erscheinungen weisen gemeinsame Merkmale mit den Dingen und Erscheinungen auf von denen sie abstammen

Das Bild ist meiner Ansicht nach sehr klar: Ein Apfel, der zu Boden fällt, wird nie weit vom Stamm des Baums entfernt zu finden sein - so wie die Eigenschaften eines Kindes denen der eigenen Eltern häufig ähnlich sind.

Im Web kursiert eine Geschichte über die Herkunft des Sprichworts, die meines Erachtens völliger Schwachsinn ist. Darin wird behauptet, das Wort *Apfel* sei eine Abwandlung des angeblich germanischen *Abfells*. Die weiteren Details der Geschichte erwähne ich nicht.

Ich habe das Wort Abfell in keiner verlässlichen Quelle gefunden. Außerdem werden auf einer der Seiten, die die Herkunft derartig beschreiben, andere Sprichwörter und Redensarten "erklärt", die auch absolut unglaubwürdig sind und auf einen fiktiven estnischen Sprachenforscher zurückgehen sollen.

Answer (score -3):

https://www.sprichwoerter.net/inhalt/artikel/sprichwoerter---ihre-bedeutung-und-ihre-herkunft.html
Pawel Gurasijewitsch: »Ich stand auf Messers Schneide!« (Ullstein Tb. 43204, Berlin, 2004) Sprichwörtersammlung mit Erläuterung. hier:

»Der Apfel fällt nicht weit vom Stamm«

Bei den alten Germanen, vor allem bei den niederdeutschen und westfälischen Sippen, gab es in vorrömischer Zeit die Institution des Abfells (ahd. Ümpel). Der Abfell war ein Zwilling, in einer Neumondnacht geboren, dessen Bruder – nur männliche Nachkommen kamen hierbei in Frage – in einer Stammesfehde gestorben war. Für einige Zeit bekam der überlebende Zwilling, der Abfell, zum Trost zahlreiche Vergünstigungen eingeräumt: Er durfte jede Nacht eine Frau seiner Wahl zu Bette führen, so viel Met trinken, wie er konnte, und im Beisein des Häuptlings Wind lassen. Dies alles um die Seele des Gestorbenen zu besänftigen. Ein Jahr nach dem Tod des Geschwister allerdings mußte nun der Abfell sich selbst vor den Palisaden des Dorfes entleiben. Daher: Der Abfell fällt (stirbt) nicht weit vom Stamm (seiner Sippe).

---

Das hört sich jedenfalls plausibler an, als alles andere, was ich bis jetzt an Erklärung dazu gefunden habe... unabhängig davon, ob jemand hier im Forum seine Meinung als Maßstab für Zensur nimmt, womöglich aus arisch-patriotischer Verwirrung.   Äpfel gab es bei den Germanen damals noch nicht, diese stammten ursprünglich aus dem Kaukasus.

Comment: Die Seite betreibt offenkundig Humbug. Das Sprichwort wird ja benutzt um auszudrücken, dass Kinder oft ähnlich werden, wie ihre Eltern waren. Das wird durch diese Erklärung aber nicht ausgedrückt. Bei den alten Germanen hat man sich wahrscheinlich noch nicht viel Gedanken um Darmwinde gemacht, lies dazu Norbert Elias, der Prozess der Zivilisation. Diese Sitten kamen erst in der höfischen Gesellschaft auf. Zwillinge in Neumondnächten geboren - das ist auch zu dick aufgetragen. Wieso diesem besonderer Trost zuteil werden soll, auch hahnebüchen. Ob die Germanen Äpfel hatten ist auch unerheblich,…

Comment: … wenn das Sprichwort gar nicht germanischen Ursprungs ist. Ohne Beleg halte ich die Behauptung, dass es in vorrömischer Zeit keine Äpfel bei den Germanen gab, für aus der Luft gegriffen. Für Zensur besteht kein Anlass - schlechte Antworten kann man auch abwerten.