# Herkunft von „Eine Schwalbe macht noch keinen Sommer“

Tags: etymology, proverb

Im Internet kursieren diverse Herleitungsversuche für ein altes Sprichwort:

> Eine Schwalbe macht noch keinen Sommer.

Welchen Ursprungs ist dieses Sprichwort nun wirklich?

Comment: Wieso nennst Du nicht die unterschiedlichen Herleitungsversuche? Sollen wir die selbst suchen, und wer sagt, dass wir die finden werden, die Du meinst?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Der Redewendungen-Duden gibt als Ursprung des Sprichwortes eine [Fabel von Äsop](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_verschwenderische_J%C3%BCngling_und_die_Schwalbe) an. In der Geschichte verkauft ein Mann seinen Mantel, weil er nach der Sichtung einer einzelnen Schwalbe davon ausgeht, dass der Sommer naht. Fortan muss er frieren, denn es bleibt kalt und die zu früh zurückgekehrte Schwalbe erfriert.

Die Geschichte, die im Internet kursiert und behauptet, das Sprichwort gehe auf zwei schwäbische Schneider zurück, ist übrigens von einem Scherzbold frei erfunden genau wie die angebliche Herkunft von *"[Der Apfel fällt nicht weit vom Stamm](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1534/sprichwort-der-apfel-fallt-nicht-weit-vom-stamm)"*.

Comment: Durch diese Antwort[http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1534/sprichwort-der-apfel-fallt-nicht-weit-vom-stamm/1537#1537] gehe ich irgendwie davon aus, dass du auf irgendeine Seite von Stupedia referenzierst. Ich verstehe ich Reaktion nicht. Kannst du bitte einen Link beistellen?

Comment: @Markus http://www.sprichwoerter.net/content/view/1467/1/

Comment: @splattne Uff...

Comment: Fabeln sind immer so brutal...

Comment: @OregonGhost Das Leben ist kein Streichelzoo. http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10624728-das-leben-ist-kein-streichelzoo

Comment: @splattne: Danke für den Tipp :)